# How do you handle dependencies between cards with Trello?

Tags: trello

I was wondering how people handle dependencies between cards in Trello.

If one of the cards needs to be Done before work can begin on another one, what do you do? These cards are big features, each having a checklist and different people working on them.

Comment: Linking Cards would be a great way to set up conditional workflows ... This would mean that a card might be 'inactive' unless the previous mandatory action is done.. not an easy thing to implement I guess..

Comment: No, and given that Fog Creek's other product, FogBugz, does not offer these kinds of dependencies, not something that's likely to happen in the software. (Probably... That's not an official position.)

Answer (score 14):

Trello does not have an official way to handle dependencies. The best thing to do is to have a "Waiting" list where you keep all the cards that are waiting on some other piece of work. If this becomes unmanageable, it's probably a sign that the board needs to be split up.

Comment: This Answer shows a built-in way that Trello links parent/child cards, using checklists: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57586/77194

Answer (score 10):

Check out [Parent/Child Management for Trello](http://labs.handsome.is/trello/) extension.

We faced the same problem for our Trello projects and have created this extension. It works great for us. Moreover, it's completely [open source](https://github.com/handsomecode/trello-parent-child), so feel free to pull source code and contribute!

Comment: Wow! this is amazing. My take is this is a different perspective and can go well with a gantt chart. I wish I could see board-wide dependencies like in a gantt chart. This is Open source, so perhaps I can provide a PR for this. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: How exactly does this extension work? Where do you store parent/child relations at?

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin there is a video on the page to watch but to be helpful, install the plugin and reload your Trello board, click on a card and you should see a "parent" and "child" button available

Comment: @Sgnl Thnks but that's not the answer of my question. I'm asking where this plugin is storing relationship information between cards.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin The child cards are stored as a checklist in the parent card. The JS then propagates the data down to the child cards.

Comment: Yes- I noticed that this was being stored as a checklist when doing a little test. I installed the plugin, set up some dependencies, and then un-installed the plugin. To my surprise, the child relationships were still there, at which point I realised they were checklists.

Comment: Cool plugin! Question: can this be extended to allow any dependency *graph* in general to be encoded, instead of just a dependency *tree*. Obviously the tree enforces acyclicity, which is nice, but it doesn't allow you to have dependencies such as A depends on B&C, which both depend on D- I think this is the simplest directed acyclic graph that can't be represented as a tree.

I believe changing this from a tree representation to a graph representation would involve making the parent a checklist also? Obviously the JS logic keeping parents/children in sync would also need to be updated.

Comment: Once there is the ability to add dependency across boards this will be perfect for us.

Comment: The plugin has a [GitHub page](https://github.com/handsomecode/trello-parent-child), and could use contributors. Recent changes in Trello have broken the plugin, and the original developers are not maintaining it.

Answer (score 9):

I've been wrestling with this too. The best solution I've found at this point is a checklist item to post a note on the dependent card. Manual process but it doesn't take that long and usually there is some communications that would help "passing the torch".

I've found by doing it this way it provides a prompt of what to do and and an automatic notification to the person assigned to the dependent card. No need to try and "train" anyone.

Answer (score 7):

[Trello Card Dependencies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-card-dependencies/ddhnhdoghhfoeceiohphmjkcemlkkock) Chrome Extension.

We wrote this to help solve the problem for us and then made it free.

Comment: This is by far the best solution on the page as of yet.

Comment: Great idea, and thanks for taking the initiative. It looks, like, however, it doesn't work for some people (per the Chrome reviews of it)

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work for me. There are a couple of errors in the console.

Comment: THIS IS THE SOLUTION

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. I can't see any cards in dependency view.

Comment: THIS WOULD BE AWESOME! ...If it worked. Unfortunately I got nothing :(

Comment: @ClayNichols et al., have you seen Sgnl's answer below? That worked for me! So did that of Danil Valov, but it forces a tree structure rather than a general graph unfortunately. Sgnl's answer for me was the best. And the UX is really nice.

Comment: Yeah... I wanted this to work so, so much. But it is truly broken. JS console errors deluxe. Would be stoked if the developer got it up and running again!

Answer (score 4):

Trello doesn't (currently) have a way to link items directly to each other.

The approach that works for me is to use a **"waiting" -label on items that are stuck.** This way they can maintain the context that their lists provide. And since items can have multiple labels it doesn't conflict with any existing labels either.

Of course, if your lists don't contain any context worth maintaining, a **separate list for waiting items** works well too.

For updating the state of the dependent card, I suggest [Bob Snodgrass's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/23278/5197) of adding a checklist item for each prerequisite card, that says "Add note on dependent card X when complete". Or if you need further organization, you could even create a "Dependencies" -checklist on the dependent card with items for each prerequisite card. Then people completing the prerequisite card can just go mark their card as done.

The best feature of Trello is how it keeps all the features simple - so that's probably why there's no dependency, since it would make things more complicate. That said, I think a feature to link items (if kept simple and clear) would be a wonderful addition, as it is a basic element of keeping work organized.

Answer (score 4):

One option to address dependencies that I've started using is leveraging the convert task to card and card link functions.  This expands on Ilari Kajaste's answer.  For example:

- Create the parent card
- Create a task list on the parent card - these tasks will become the child cards
- Convert the tasks to cards (Click on the task to enter edit mode, click "Convert to Card" link
- A new card will be created (using the same title as the converted task), and in it's activity notes will be a link back to the parent card.  I copy this link into the description or into a new checklist task for transparency - the original link may eventually be buried under later activity notes.
- To tie child back to parent, click the "More" link at the bottom right hand corner of the child card and copy the shortcut link from the "Link to this Card" field
- Navigate back to the parent card via the link in the activity notes (or closing the card and navigating manually) and add the child card link in the parent description, task list or other convenient place.

The owner of the parent card can check off the dependent tasks as they are completed.  This is straight forward using the links added in the last point above. Alternatively, the owner of one of the child cards can have a final task to navigate back to the parent card and check off the initial task.

A nice feature of this process is that if these child cards are later moved to another board, the links persist.  The product owner can create the relationships on a planning board, move cards willy nilly and still have easy access to and from those cards where ever they land.  Even if the manual copying / pasting of links is not completed, there will always be at least this one artifact of the original parentage in the child card.

The downside is there is at least one manual step (copying child card link to parent card) to create a solid relationship, but overall is a good alternative to the more management heavy processes such as maintaining separate "waiting" lists and describing the dependent cards.

Comment: This appears to be the "native" and free method of making Dependencies that is built into Trello.

Comment: Could you make a Button to automate this?  Too bad that the Checklist:"Convert to Card" button doesn't already produce a link to the Child card.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimello has support for such a feature, they have it labeled as: "Connected Cards" and it's currently in beta phase but you can try it by installing the app

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm?hl=en-US

Caveat from comments via Colm:

> For future users: make sure you click the "Authorize" button on the plugin's Chrome settings or it won't show in Trello for you

Comment: This is awesome! It's the only one of the bunch that I tried that both:
 - Let's you do multiple parents & multiple children AND
 - Actually works!
Also there are extra features & the usability is really nice.

For future users: make sure you click the "Authorize" button on the plugin's Chrome settings or it won't show in Trello for you!

Answer (score 1):

We have written a ["Links" addon for Trello](http://www.tai.st/addons/trello-links) that adds JIRA-like dependencies - with various types like "depends on" or "blocks".

It doesn't modify card contents to store dependencies - they are stored in additional storage provided by Taist - this is our platform for creating addons to cloud applications.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Will this work in a team?

Comment: The link is this answer leads to an un-secure site. seems the SSL cert is expired or invalid

Answer (score 1):

There's a free Power-Up that allows to set dependencies between cards: [Card Dependencies for Trello](https://screenful.com/card-dependencies-for-trello)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set due date per card and then use the Butler Power Up to sort by date. Thus, the ones due later are dependent on the card above being done first.

Answer (score 0):

We built a Trello Power-Up to do this. It allows you to create parent-child card dependencies across boards. https://helloepics.com/