# Setting up a workflow in Trello

Tags: trello, user-accounts

Is there any way to set up dependencies across cards? That is, Card B cannot be changed/completed/marked done unless Card A is set to done.
Alternatively, it could be nice to be able to assign each item in a check list to a different user (one Card is a global action, that requires N people to each do the item they are assigned to).

Comment: Maybe you're helped by the answer on the [How do you handle dependencies between cards with Trello?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/how-do-you-handle-dependencies-between-cards-with-trello) question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Trello user too and so far I haven't found any dependency feature provided by Trello. All current available features are listed here: https://trello.com/guide