# On Trello is it possible to make a card dependent on another card?

Tags: trello

In your task list on Trello can you mark one card as a dependent on another card? For example, you can't put the tree in the ground (task 2) until you've dug the hole (task 1).

Comment: I don't think you can currently but it would be nice to be able to have this. In programming I have classes that are dependent on others, and they cannot be completed until the other is as well. I guess almost inheriting or sub classing would be cool to be added in Trello

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you handle dependencies between cards with Trello?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/how-do-you-handle-dependencies-between-cards-with-trello)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've recently moved the [Dependencies Between Cards](https://trello.com/card/dependencies-between-cards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1274) feature to the main Trello board. That card will be forum for further discussion of supporting this use case.

Comment: A year and a half have since passed. What is the current state of development? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Trello Card Dependencies Chrome Extension.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-card-dependencies/ddhnhdoghhfoeceiohphmjkcemlkkock)

We wrote this to help solve the problem for us and then made it free.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a formal way to do this, but you could use some combination of vertical position, comments, and description to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free Power-Up that can do that: [Card Dependencies for Trello](https://screenful.com/card-dependencies-for-trello)